# Getting exhausted gas operation while interacting with the contract

Tags: gas

Hello we have a transaction that is failing due to the error
tezos: kind=temporary, id=proto.017-PtNairob.gas_exhausted.operation
both from the BCD UI and tzgo aswell.

We have an entrypoint handle_relay_message on the ghostnet. Here is the link of the contract.
https://better-call.dev/ghostnet/KT1HBboTBRxjcL3KAcYbN81rnsRkz8u1Wnao/interact/handle_relay_message

The parameters are
msg =
`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`
and prev = `btp://0x7.icon/cxd2d1738cfa7c8b1278452637a66370e66e74af1b`

msg is bytes and prev is string

While simulating on BCD, it shows that the transaction is passed but while simulating through tzgo it says gas exhausted operations.

And the wallet address to call the operation is
`tz1dheF62PzopJviUxDBjUx6KfNwH7K5pqRE`

can you guys help us out here ?

Comment: please edit your question and provide reproducible steps, this error can happen for many reasons, its not possible to give any guidance without seeing whats happening. Please provide the JSON payload being sent to the simulation API and the JSON response you get back

Answer (score 1):

According to this [operation](https://better-call.dev/ghostnet/opg/ooY2QLxcyi2FMvVSVQjrjzRe2StCX4Djq1c1SPG14UymXRVkMRx/contents), the call you are trying to make seems to consume more than the 1,040,000 gas limit for an operation. So you need somehow to reduce the gas consumption of the contract, the call to `handle_btp_message` is responsible for the large consumption. Maybe you can do it in two steps?

Comment: Is there any way we can increase gas limit more than this and do a transaction ?

Comment: No, the point of this limit is to protect nodes from operations taking too much resources.

Comment: so will this be possible , if i run my own node and I don't have any issues on taking much resources ?

Comment: @Kin no these are hard limits. The only way to increase it is to propose a protocol upgrade with the code containing an increase to this. It would need to be heavily tested and agreed by the community. Likely you will need to find a way to improve your contract code, as the limit is already quite high